# Does rebalance occur when new multithreaded consumer is added to a group

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's assume that there is only one topic with 20 partitions and one consumer group with only one consumer instance that consumes from that topic.

If this consumer instance have 20 threads, after rebalance Kafka will assign each partition to one thread and this is ideal (one thread to one partition)

But at this point; what happens if another consumer instance with 20 threads added to this consumer group?

I guess the options would be like this;

1 - Rebalance wouldn't occur and second consumer stay in a idle state. (Because 20 threads are enough already for 20 partitions)

2 - Rebalance occurs and 10 partitions are assigned to first consumer and other 10 partitions are assigned to second consumer. (10 threads for each consumer will be idle)

Actually second option is more ideal I guess. Because we split the work by adding another instance.

So which scenario would happen in this situation? Can Kafka handle this case smootly? Or adding another instance is just a waste?

Edit: I used the word "instance" as a microservice instance not the KafkaConsumer instance btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How topic's partitions are assigned depends on `PartitionAssignor`, that is used by group leader of the consumer group.
First Consumer from group that joins to the group become the leader. If new consumer joins to already running group,
Consumer `Leader` based on its `PartitionAssignor` assign partitions to particular consumer from the group.

You can set `PartitionAssignor` using `partition.assignment.strategy`. Default value is `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor`.
If you want to change the assignment strategy for your group you can use different one or implement custom one.

If you go to javadoc of `RangeAssignor` https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html, you can find as follow:

> The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. 
>   For each topic, we lay out the available partitions in numeric order and the consumers in lexicographic order. 
>   We then divide the number of partitions by the total number of consumers to determine the number of partitions to assign to each consumer. 
>   If it does not evenly divide, then the first few consumers will have one extra partition. 
>   For example, suppose there are two consumers C0 and C1, two topics t0 and t1, and each topic has 3 partitions, resulting in partitions t0p0, t0p1, t0p2, t1p0, t1p1, and t1p2. 
>   The assignment will be: C0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1] C1: [t0p2, t1p2]

**In you case** (`RangeAssignor`) you dont' know if *new threads* will be idle or not.
It depends on consumer ids, that it gets, ex.  1st *thread* in *new instance* might be idle, but 2nd might start processing data.

*Update according to new information in question*

Comment: Actually I create new KafkaConsumer for each thread. I mean the word "instance" as a microservice instance. At the beginning I have one microservice instance with 20 threads that has own KafkaConsumer and then I add new microservice instance that has 20 threads also. (and of course both of the instances are in the same consumer group)

I hope I clearly explain myself now.

Comment: @H.Ç.T, I've update might answer according to your supplement.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another Kafka consumer is of no use here. All the threads in the second consumer would remain idle.
One partition can be assigned to one consumer only. Although, the reverse is not true. One consumer can read data from n-partitions.
Although I would not say that it's a total waste to add the second consumer. Your second consumer would act as a HA. In case your first consumer app dies, the second consumer app would start getting data from Kafka.